# How to validate 2D array values in Java

Tags: java, validation

I am new to Java and having difficulty performing input validation on a 2D array of integers.
I am trying to check to determine if the array has had any negative integers added and if so to then throw an exception.

What I have tried is:

```
int [][] myArray = {
        {2,-2,2,2},
        {3,3,3,3}};

for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++){
                 if(myArray[1] < 0 ){
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative integer.");
            }
        }
```

However, as many will probably gather from looking at my code, I get the error

```
Incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
```

Is there a way to perform input validation in some way to check for non-positive integers? I have so far not been able to come up with a good solution or work around.

Comment: In java multidimensional arrays are arrays of arrays. So the value at myArray[1] is an int array, not a specific int value. More specifically it's the array `{3,3,3,3}` from your example. To get it to work you'd need to use `myArray[i][j]`

Comment: You have two nested loops, and the code inside the nested loops fails to use *either* of the loop variables at all. That should be a red flag to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close

Since you need to provide the exact "co-ordinates" of the numbers, all you have to do is to replace `myArray[1]` with `myArray[i][j]`

```
int [][] myArray = {
        {2,-2,2,2},
        {3,3,3,3}};

for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++){
                 if(myArray[i][j] < 0 ){
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative integer.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I was getting stuck with visualizing things in a "row" and "column" mentality and thinking that I could access "rows" as myArray[rows] instead of the entire structure as you have showed ```myArrays[rowIndex][columnIndex]``` That makes sense.

Comment: You can access them whole rows at a time, but you will get a `Integer[]` instead of a single `Integer`, and `Integer[]` cannot be compared with numbers, that's where the mistake was. You did access them as whole rows in the question, just the comparison was incorrect 